# Using preprocessor directives in with VS 2022 and C# makes code lose syntax coloring and squiggles

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a class library that targets dotnet standard 2.1 and dotnet framework 4.6. I am trying to use pre-processor directives to mark code that is framework specific, but I am losing colors and error highlighting. But only in between the NETSTANDARD2_1 blocks.

How can I fix this? I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview 4.

[image: Difference between NET46 and NETSTANDARD2_1 pre-processor directives]

Comment: This is normal behavior.  Compiler is only checking code it will compile for active pre-processor directives.  When you switch to NETSTANDARD2_1 you should see this block displayed as you'd expect.

Comment: How do I switch to NETSTANDARD2_1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing is the navigation bar. I never knew that's what it was called. You can drop this down and select the different framework contexts and your code will then be color highlited.
[image]

Comment: Would be nice if that was automatically sync'd to the platform selector.

Comment: Hi Dbloom, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. Just a reminder :)